# Choose a Specific Entity Framework 7 (Core 1) Migration in Code

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to programmatically specify an EF7 migration in a console application. In EF6 the code looked something like this

```
     var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator( someDbMigrationsConfiguration );

     dbMigrator.Update( "NameOfMyMigration" );
```

With EF7 the following code will run all of the migrations

```
     using ( var db = new someDbContext() )
     {
        db.Database.Migrate();
     }
```

But I can't find any examples or documentation on how to specify a specific migration like I'm able to do with EF6. This is using EF 7.0.0-rc1-final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, despite spending the better part of this afternoon searching for an answer I found one nearly immediately after posting. Here's the EF7 equivalent:

```
using ( var db = new someDbContext() )
{
   var migrator = db.GetInfrastructure().GetRequiredService<IMigrator>();
   migrator.Migrate( "NameOfMyMigration" );
}
```